# Why is $\frac{\partial x}{\partial y} = \frac{dx/dt}{dy/dt}$ if $x$ and $y$ are unknown?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, partial-derivative, dynamical-systems

Given $\frac{dx}{dt} = f(x,y,t)$ and $\frac{dy}{dt} = g(x,y,t)$. Suppose the explicit form of $x$ and $y$ are unsolvable, then the phase plane is usually considered by looking at $\frac{dx}{dy}$. This represents how much $x$ varies with respect to $y$, which is also $\frac{\partial x}{\partial y}$. Thus, $$\frac{\partial x}{\partial y} = \frac{dx/dt}{dy/dt}.$$

This means that without knowing $x$ and $y$, I can find the derivative of $x$ with respect to $y$ and vice versa. *Is there any problem with this?*

In a hand-wavy manner, I am wondering if the last equality in the following makes sense
$$\frac{\partial x}{\partial y} = \frac{\partial x}{\partial t}
\frac{\partial t}{\partial y} = \frac{\partial x/\partial t}{\partial y/\partial t}
= \frac{dx}{dy}.$$

As Lee Mosher points out, the case of $dy/dt=0$ (or even $dy/dt \equiv 0$) needs to be considered separately. For this question, I am most interested in the case when $dy/dt >0$.

Comment: Clarification needed: Partial derivatives are used when one variable depends on several and keeping some fixed. "How much $x$ varies with respect to $y$" but keeping what fixed?

Comment: @Chrystomath I dont think it's needed, the OP has supplied that $dx/dt$ and $dy/dt$ is a function of (x,y,t) , which means that $(a(t),b(t))$ are its parametric coordinates, so $a^{-1}x=t=b^{-1}x$, by doing this we get $$[\frac{dy}{dx}]_{\text{at any (x,y)}}$$

Comment: I was thinking it may probably make sense along the line of the parametric parameter $t$, but I am not 100% certain.

Comment: How do you get from $\frac{\frac{\partial x}{\partial t}}{\frac{\partial y}{\partial t}}$ to $\frac{dx}{dt}$?  Take, for example: $x(t)=t^4, y(t)=t^2$ and look at each step of your equality, and you'll find that the jump is invalid

Comment: @Moko19 Apology for the typo. It's supposed to be $\frac{dx}{dy}$. In your example, $dx/dt = 4t^3$ and $dy/dt = 2t$, so $dx/dy = 2t^2 = 2y$. Similarly, $x = t^4 = y^2$, so $dx/dy = 2y$ as well.

Comment: Well, this certainly breaks down at points where $dy/dt=0$.

Comment: @LeeMosher I agree. $dy/dt = 0$ is indeed a special case that needs to be considered separately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The expression
$$
\frac{dx}{dy}=\frac{dx/dt}{dy/dt}
$$
is shorthand for one of two more complicated expressions:
$$
X^\prime(z)=\frac{x^\prime(T(z))}{y^\prime(T(z))}
$$
or
$$
X^\prime(y(t))=\frac{x^\prime(t)}{y^\prime(t)}\ ,
$$
where $\ T\ $ is an inverse of $\ y\ $ over some domain, and $\ X(z)=x(T(z))\ $.  These identities are derived by differentiating the identities
\begin{align}
y(T(z))&=z\ \text{ and}\\
X(z)&=x(T(z))\ ,
\end{align}
with respect to $\ z\ $.  All the functions here are functions of a *single* variable. While it's strictly speaking not an *error* to denote the derivative of a function $\ \phi(\theta)\ $ of a single variable $\ \theta\ $ by the expression $\ \frac{\partial\phi}{\partial{\theta}}\ $, I can't see how that would ever serve any useful purpose, and it's apt to be confusing, so I'd strongly suggest not doing so.

The components $\ (x, y)\ $ of any solution to your differential equations are functions of a *single* variable $\ t\ $.  If you define $\ X\ $ and $\ T\ $ as above you will have
\begin{align}
X^\prime(z)&= \frac{x^\prime(T(z))}{y^\prime(T(z))}\\
&=\frac{f\left(X(z),z, T(z)\right)}{g\left(X(z),z, T(z)\right)}\ .
\end{align}
When either $\ f\ $ or $\ g\ $ depend explicitly on their third argument $\ t\ $, this isn't much help, because you can't normally find out what $\ T\ $ is until you've already obtained the function $\ y\ $. However, if neither $\ f\ $ nor $\ g \ $ depends expicitly on its third argument, then the equation becomes
$$
X'(z)= \frac{f\left(X(z),z\right)}{g\left(X(z),z\right)}\ ,\\
$$
which you can write, using the customary shorthand as
$$
\frac{dx}{dy}=\frac{f(x,y)}{g(x,y)}\ .
$$
Now it may well be possible to integrate this differential equation to find an  expression for $\ x\ $ in terms of $\ y\ $, even when it has not been possible to find an expression for $\ y\ $ in terms of $\ t\ $.